# Error while using unzip with 12mb file size

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, unzip

Im using the following open source to unzip file and its working as expected on
zip with size 2-5 MB but when I put zip on 10 more MB I got error,
there is more stable open source which I can use for large zip files?
I need it to be under MIT license.
 this is what I've used 
https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip

```
var extractor = unzip.Extract({ path: "../"});

extractor.on("close", function() {
    console.log("Success unzip");
});

extractor.on("close", function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

req.pipe(extractor);
```

Comment: i've used jszip on large zips (dozens of MB). might need some tweaking to get to work on node, but i think  there are examples abound.

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: @prasun - I got invalid signature ...whic is not related to the real issue I guess which is the file size....

Comment: https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip/issues/52 does this relate to yours?

Comment: @prasun - maybe but there is no place which is written that this error is thrown in large zip fiels...

Comment: @shopiaT on the reverse side how can you conclude your error is due to large file , not the file itself?

Comment: @prasun - Hi not sure that I got your question?

Comment: I meant how are you so sure that the error you are getting is due to large file size only, not any other reason

Comment: @prasun - I try to play with just the files size for the same project type and structure and when the zip is become larger the 10mb I got this error,there is other open source which you recomended to use?

Comment: Which version of the package are you running and which version of Node are you using? Do you have a full example of how are you using `unzip`? I just unzipped a 182MB text file without any problems.

Comment: I think your problem may be related to your input source, not to zip lib. I noticed you are trying to pipe from a request, and it may be limited to 10Mb. How are you building this request? Express? Http?

Comment: Have you tried using the node built-in `zlib`? Also you have to supply more code for us, and you have 2 event listeners `on "close"`, instead of `error`

Comment: first try to pipe this zip file into a file on your filesystem. Then check if the saved zip file can be unzipped manually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to this issue of the unzip github page - https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip/issues/73,

- the unzip module is not supported anymore.
- a problem related to streaming from http seem to have been solved in a fork called unzip2 (which is also very old)

try with

```
npm install unzip2
```

there are also other zip MIT modules you can try :

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/julien-f-unzip

you can also find this library - https://www.npmjs.com/package/yauzl which explains why the 'zip' file format is not very well suited to streaming.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/yauzl#no-streaming-unzip-api

> Due to the design of the .zip file format, it's impossible to
>   interpret a .zip file from start to finish (such as from a readable
>   stream) without sacrificing correctness. The Central Directory, which
>   is the authority on the contents of the .zip file, is at the end of a
>   .zip file, not the beginning. A streaming API would need to either
>   buffer the entire .zip file to get to the Central Directory before
>   interpreting anything (defeating the purpose of a streaming
>   interface), or rely on the Local File Headers which are interspersed
>   through the .zip file. However, the Local File Headers are explicitly
>   denounced in the spec as being unreliable copies of the Central
>   Directory, so trusting them would be a violation of the spec.
>
> Any library that offers a streaming unzip API must make one of the
>   above two compromises, which makes the library either dishonest or
>   nonconformant (usually the latter). This library insists on
>   correctness and adherence to the spec, and so does not offer a
>   streaming API.

there are 354 results to "unzip" on NPM - https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=unzip

whatever library you choose, make sure to first write a node.js program using this library that extracts the content of you errored zip file directly from the filesystem.

Once this works, you will be able to add the web server additional complexity.

Answer (score 1):

i would use the CloudConvert api they have an npm that can handle this. the example code for it can be found [in their documentation](https://cloudconvert.com/apiconsole) the node specific example is this

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    cloudconvert = new (require('cloudconvert'))(''); // install using 'npm install cloudconvert'

fs.createReadStream('input.format').pipe(cloudconvert.convert({
"input": "upload"
}).on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('Failed: ' + err);
}).on('finished', function(data) {
    console.log('Done: ' + data.message);
    this.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.format'));
}).on('downloaded', function(destination) {
    console.log('Downloaded to: ' + destination.path);
}));
```

you do need internet connection in order for this to work. As for the MIT license obviously this is an api not independent code. But the functionality and reliability of it are going to be more then anything on the local system. And it is free if that is your worry about the MIT license. If your wanting an MIT license so you can edit it and manipulate it this might not work.